# TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for &: 'sage.rings.rational.Rational' and 'int'

Tags: python, encryption, cryptography, sage

So for my cryptography course we were given an assignment and on problem 1 we had to write in the rest of the function for Solovay-Strassen Primality Test and heres what I wrote out:

```
def SolovayStrassen(n,k):
    for i in [1..k]:
        a = randint(2,n-1) #picks a random number between 2 and n-1
        j = jacobi_symbol(a,n) #computes jacobi function
        p = power_mod(a,(n-1)/2,n) #uses the power mod function 
        #now we test if both are equal to find if both are equal in order to check if the number is "composite" or "probably prime"
        if (j != p):
            return False #"composite"
    return True #"probably prime"
```

Now mind you this is being complied in sage online but when I run the code it pops up with this error message

```
Error in lines 2-2
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/cocalc/lib/python2.7/site-packages/smc_sagews/sage_server.py", line 1013, in execute
    exec compile(block+'\n', '', 'single') in namespace, locals
  File "", line 1, in <module>
  File "", line 5, in SolovayStrassen
  File "/ext/sage/sage-8.1/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sage/arith/misc.py", line 1939, in power_mod
    while n&1 == 0:
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for &: 'sage.rings.rational.Rational' and 'int'
```

It looks like its referring to this line of where the error seems to occur

```
 p = power_mod(a,(n-1)/2,n) #uses the power mod function
```

I assume that the error maybe that its trying to convert a rational number to an integer based on the power_mod function?

Comment: Take a look at your for loop, [1..k] is what?

Comment: @MikiBelavista that is fine in sage. it produces a `list`.

Comment: k = the number of iterations that the executes so its from 1 to k

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use the `//` operator for integer division. The `/` operator will produce a rational number in Sagemath if the numerator is not divisible by the denominator. I suspect that your algorithm should not be attempted on even values of `n` anyway, which is the only way this problem could manifest itself. Even `n` are usually treated as a special case because their primality is so easy to determine.

Comment: Okay that did it! Thank you! and I did not know that! I'm still getting used to using SAGE still even though its similar but different in many ways when it comes to its programming and compiler functionality